# Convert Date from dd-MMM-yy to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am getting date from a csv file and is in the format eg. 06-Aug-2021 . I need to convert to yyyy-MM-dd so 2021-08-06

I tried

```
TRANSACTION_DATE as Date {"format": "dd-MMM-yy"} as String {"format": "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

I am getting an error as below

Cannot coerce String (06-Aug-2021) to Date, caused by: Text '06-Aug-2021' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 9
I am using dataweave 2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After posting I tried the below and it worked vars.transactionDate as Date {"format": "dd-MMM-yyyy"} as Date {"format": "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"}

Comment: You should enter what you discovered as an Answer to your own question, then accept it.

Comment: That should not work, a Date has no time and the format should fail with a cause similar to `Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm`.

Answer (score 0):

The format for year in the first conversion is too short ('yy') it needs four digits for year ('yyyy').

Example:

Input: `"06-Aug-2021"`

Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload as Date {"format": "dd-MMM-yyyy"} as String {"format": "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

Output:
`"2021-08-06"`